# Data binding to a list and picking elements randomly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list for which each item has the following data template:

```
<stack Panel>
    <TextBlock Text={Binding SomeText} />
    <stackPanel Tag={Binding SecondText}>
        <TextBlock = {Binding RandomText} />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

where SomeTextClass is

```
public SomeTextClass
{
    public string SomeText{get; set;}
    public string SecondText{get; set;}
    public string ThirdText{get; set;}
}
```

I am also parsing an xml file to get `List<SomeTextClass>` and then binding the ListBox source to the `List<SomeTextClass>`

Suppose the `List<SomeTextClass>` has the following format:
**Item1 object**: `SomeText1, SecondText1, ThirdText1`
**Item2 object**: `SomeText2, SecondText2, ThirdText2`
**Item3 object**: `SomeText3, SecondText3, ThirdText3`

To the first TextBlock, and second StackPanel tag, I want to assign the `SomeText`, `SecondText` which is fine and working as well. But to the inner TextBlock, I want to assign the `ThirdText` in a random manner and not in order which appears in the list?

How can that be done when I am binding the listbox to the List ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of two ways:

1. Assign the random values to the ThirdText properties directly (or introduce a fourth property for the random value). This will allow your binding to remain simple.
2. Bind the inner TextBlock text to the entire list, and create an IValueConverter to return a random value from the list.